# Get a boolean of a map

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

I have a `private final Map<Long, Boolean> rpenabled = new HashMap<>();` and did this so it sets it to `true` when the bot is online or got added to a server:

```
public void onGuildReady(@NotNull GuildReadyEvent event) {
        rpenabled.get(event.getGuild().getIdLong());
        rpenabled.get(event.getGuild().getIdLong());

        rpenabled.put(event.getGuild().getIdLong(), true);
        gifenabled.put(event.getGuild().getIdLong(), false);
    }
```

after that i wanted to use the map in an onMessageReceivedEvent and tried that with

```
if (rpenabled.values().contains(true)) {

                    rpenabled.put(event.getGuild().getIdLong(), false);

                    event.getChannel().sendMessage("<:relationships_true:1075825708355555578> The `Roleplay Commands` module has successfully been **disabled**.").queue();

                }
```

and

```
if (rpenabled.containsKey(true)) {

                    rpenabled.put(event.getGuild().getIdLong(), false);

                    event.getChannel().sendMessage("<:relationships_true:1075825708355555578> The `Roleplay Commands` module has successfully been **disabled**.").queue();

                }
```

after I implemented the maps with

```
public void onMessageReceived(@NotNull MessageReceivedEvent event) {

        rpenabled.get(event.getGuild().getIdLong());
        gifenabled.get(event.getGuild().getIdLong());
```

It's not working properly though. Does anyone know why and how I can fix that?

Comment: Ok, and what is not going well?

Comment: `rpenabled.containsKey(true)` will always return false because the keys in your map are `Long`. And `rpenabled.values().contains(true)` will return true if any of your map entries has a `true` value. You probably want to query the map with `rpenabled.get(event.getGuild().getIdLong())` which will return the boolean value associated with the id of the events guild.

Comment: The question should be edit to reflect actual and desired behavior.

Comment: @ThomasKläger tysm it works now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rpenabled.containsKey(true)` will always return false because the keys in your map are `Long`.

And `rpenabled.values().contains(true)` will return true if any of your map entries has a `true` value.

You probably want to query the map with `rpenabled.get(event.getGuild().getIdLong())` which will return the boolean value associated with the id of the events guild.

Basically a `Map<Long, Boolean>` is not that different from a `Map<Long, Int>`: you can use `put(key, value)` to store a value into the map and you use `get(key)` to retrieve the value associated with a key. The only distinction is the type of the value.

---

Additional note:

I don't understand what you want to achieve with

```
    rpenabled.get(event.getGuild().getIdLong());
    gifenabled.get(event.getGuild().getIdLong());
```

in the `onMessageReceived()` method or with the repeated

```
    rpenabled.get(event.getGuild().getIdLong());
    rpenabled.get(event.getGuild().getIdLong());
```

in the `onGuildReady()` method. Those statements access the map but throw away the result.